# PostGIS ST_SnapToGrid only partially working

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to use `ST_SnapToGrid(geometry geomA, float size);` on PostGIS 2.5.2 but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  function public.st_snaptogrid(geometry, integer, integer, double precision, double precision) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT public.ST_SnapToGrid($1, 0, 0, $2, $3)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The same happens with the examples in the [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html), the first example runs fine but the second one returns the same error:

```
SELECT ST_SnapToGrid(
    ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(-1.1115678 2.123 2.3456 1.11111,4.111111 3.2374897 3.1234 1.1111, -1.11111112 2.123 2.3456 1.1111112)'),
    ST_GeomFromEWKT('POINT(1.12 2.22 3.2 4.4444)'),
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01);


SELECT ST_SnapToGrid(
    ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1.1115678 2.123, 4.111111 3.2374897, 4.11112 3.23748667)'),
    0.001);
```

### Update

I'm using the `mdillon/postgis` Docker image and move PostGIS like this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA abc;
ALTER SCHEMA abc OWNER TO abc;
UPDATE pg_extension SET extrelocatable = TRUE WHERE extname = 'postgis';
ALTER EXTENSION postgis set schema abc;
```

Comment: can you add the information from these query? `SELECT postgis_full_version()` and `SELECT version()`? I suspect your PostGIS isn't properly installed. Your queries are just fine - tested on 2.5 and 3.0

Comment: @JimJones `PostgreSQL 11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit` but `SELECT postgis_full_version()` fails with `No function matches the given name and argument types.`, again referring to `public`. I double checked and the search path corresponds to the schema where PostGIS is installed.

Comment: If not even `postgis_full_version()` is found, it means your query has no access to the postgis functions - different schema. Is `create extension postgis;` in your current schema an option for you?

Comment: @JimJones `ERROR:  extension "postgis" already exists`. See update in my question as well.

Comment: I can now reproduce your error. It smells like a bug in postgis.. I suspect that somewhere in the function the schema is hardcoded :( if you found a solution, please post it here! +1

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the extension (and, as a consequence, the function) is installed in a schema different from `public`.

In `psql`, run `\dx postgis` to see in which schema PostGIS is installed.

You **cannot** change an extension's schema by modifying the catalog. Doing that will break your database.

Comment: The extension is indeed installed in another schema, but that schema is in my search path. As far as I know that would also not explain that other example does work.

Comment: Oh yes it does, because you explicitly reference the `public` schema, so the `search_path` is not used.

Comment: I'm not referencing the `public` schema in my queries and `show search_path;` only returns my schema.

Comment: Cannot be. The error message quotes your SQL: `SELECT public.ST_SnapToGrid($1, 0, 0, $2, $3)`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm not sure if it is a bug or a feature:) But even after changing the schema of postgis the function `ST_SnapshotToGrid(geometry, double precision)`  still points to `public`. What do you think? I could make it work by changing the `schema` manually - see answer above - but I am not quite happy/sure with it. Schöne Grüße nach Wien.

Comment: You cannot change the schema of PostgGIS  unless you deinstall and reinstall it, which would delete the old function. What exactly did you do?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe see the update in the question. It is possible to set a different schema after installation. `UPDATE pg_extension SET extrelocatable = TRUE WHERE extname = 'postgis';
ALTER EXTENSION postgis set schema abc;` - after that some functions stop working. I checked their code and there was a "hard coded" `public` in the function call... that's why I created it again with the new schema.

Comment: By updating the catalog table you broke the extension. This will blow up sooner or later. Undo that catalog change quickly. The only way to move the extension is to uninstall and reinstall it. Or you use it in the schema where it currently is.

Comment: I'm afraid that what you're suggesting is indeed the best solution. I also wouldn't dare to do such a change, but I believe the OP didn't have the luxury of a different scenario:)